# Why is there so much space around the image?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I have a question about layout.

I have this `ImageView`:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/informacionpersonal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="@string/layout_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But on eclipse designer I see it:

[image]

**Why is there so much space around the image?** I've used `wrap_content`.

This is the image. You can see there isn't any margin or white space around it.
[image]

Comment: Hi VansFannel, The below answer is not exactly correct..This is the problem for , remove the imageview properties layout_marginLeft="10dp" ,      layout_marginRight="10dp".. why because, those properties are accepted only parent layout of that imageview. this is the problem you have in your code.

Comment: Hi Vans,Remove this android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" properties in your imageview. give it to parent layout if you want that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Scaletype option in properties of ImageView and select fitXY .That should stetch the image to the imageview

Answer (score 2):

Set the image as ImageView background it will be solved

```
android:background="@drawable/informacionpersonal"
```

Comment: what is the deference between your code and mine @harikrishnan

Comment: I said, the layout alignment properties need to remove from imageview, its accepted only parent layouts ,for the above mentioned problem. thats it..

Comment: you said for, normal set background image is not related to above mentioned problem.the problem is for only, why space is coming.. not image set to background. you just execute my code, what Vans asked question above, I given answer here.. fine..

Comment: Thanks for your reply @harikrishnan . But i didn't find any document where it say's alignment is for only parent layout. And please add an image in ImageView as a source see what happen and then remove the source and again add that image as a background. See the deference.

Answer (score 0):

I used here for ic_launcher icon. its working correct.. try this..

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```